# Fields and methods of metatable are not visible on table right after setmetatable

Tags: lua, pico-8

This is Pico-8 lua. I have the following function, which fails at the marked assert. I do not understand how this can happen. I have used `setmetatable` on two other occasions and it is working there. I have no clue here.

```
function particle:new(o)
    setmetatable(o, self)
    assert(self.spd, "works")
    assert(getmetatable(o).spd, "works")
    assert(o.spd, "this fails") -- < this assert fails, the ones above succeed
    add(anims,o)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot

```
self.__index = self
```

Without this `o.spd` will not refer to `particle.spd`, if `o.spd` is nil.

Comment: Thanks so much. I still don't understand all this.

Comment: if there is something particular you don't understand you can always post a question here.